# Is the covariant derivative of the inverse metric zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity, mathematical-astronomy

I know that covariant derivative of metric is zero [[source](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47919/why-is-the-covariant-derivative-of-the-metric-tensor-zero), and my lecture notes confirm this]: $$\nabla _{\mu}g_{\alpha \beta} = 0,$$
How can I know if $$\nabla _{\mu}g^{\alpha \beta} = 0?$$

Comment: It would be most natural, I think, to explore this through differentiating the Kronecker delta $g_{\alpha\beta}g^{\beta\gamma}$ using the product rule.

Comment: Oh thanks. Yes, that makes sense.